# installing oracle in windows azure under VM

Tags: oracle, azure-virtual-machine

I am thinking of using windows azure for my next project. I am forced to use oracle as the db back end. I would like to know whether there is any possibility of installing oracle on a windows azure virtual machine?

Comment: I don't think there is any fundamental *technical* barriers to installing Oracle on Azure.  What may trip you up is *licensing*: Oracle is notoriously hard-nosed when it comes to licensing its software on VMs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually windows azure vms are like the typical servers only difference is they are in the cloud. You need to copy the installation files to the VM. I need to sort out the requirements before installing in the VM. Like RAM, Hard Disk, and etc.